# Reading json data from file getting blank response

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am getting empty response while reading json content from file please find below snippet which I am using in my code and json file from which I am trying to read data.

```
$http.get('content/json/environment.json').success(function(data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('payload')){
                data = data.payload;
            }               
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
```

environment.json file

```
 {
    "payload": {
        "environment": [
            {
                "environment": "Production"
            },
            {
                "environment": "QA1"
            },
            {
                "environment": "QA2"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Comment: use `data.data`

Comment: Hi , I tried now I am getting "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"

Comment: look your `data.data` in `console.log(data.data)` if it really return the json

Comment: ya getting undefined

Comment: $.getJSON( "content/json/environment.json", function( data ) {});

Comment: Hi Soni, it is also not helping

Comment: do I need to send content-type: application/json in the request because in my request it is going as text/plain ?

Answer (score 2):

Your response will be inside data.data

```
$http.get('content/json/environment.json').success(function(data) {
            if(data.data.hasOwnProperty('payload')){
                data = data.data.payload;
            }               
            deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2n2vd9dLs34iAtLmAiKx?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi Sajeev, I tried now I am getting "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"

Comment: add a console.log and check if you can see the data console.log(data.data)

Comment: getting undefined

Comment: @Mayur check this demo https://plnkr.co/edit/2n2vd9dLs34iAtLmAiKx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Sajeev, not sure why in project it is not loading like it.. even I added enviroment.json in public folder and trying to access it directly through URL but getting empty response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135234/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-mayur).

Comment: do I need to send content-type: application/json in the request because in my request it is going as text/plain ?